# Unable to call Javascript from Blazor. Could not find 'startDataTable' in 'window'

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables, blazor

I'm trying to use Blazor and DataTables.net component to add sorting functions to a table. Only the following syntax has allowed me to use Javascript Interop in Blazor:

**datatable.js**

```
window.methods = {
    startDataTable: function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#table').DataTable();
        });
    },
    showAlert: function () {
        alert("waht up");
    }
}
```

The showAlert function is executed when I call it from Blazor component. But if I use the startDataTable function, nothing happens. Is it something missing?

**List.razor**

```
 @if (!@ToggleList)
        {
            <table id="table" data-toggle="table" class="table table-responsive" data-sortable="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Key</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Graduates</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Exams</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Exams finished</th>
                        <th data-sortable="true">Percentage</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in States)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@item.Icveie</td>
                            <td @onclick="() => showCz(item.Icveie)">@item.Cdesie</td>
                            <td>@item.Ucn</td>
                            <td>@item.Exa_pre</td>
                            <td>@item.Exa_acre</td>
                            <td>@item.Porc_acre</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("methods.showAlert");
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="../js/datatable.js"></script>
```

I'm using Blazor with ASP.NET Core 3.1. My intention is to use DataTables.net component to add extra functions to a table. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, I think it would be worth to take a look at `OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstrender)`

From what I have read, JS is rendered last and therefore cannot be used in `OnInitializedAsync`.

MS Docs describe this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-3.1#after-component-render

From the documentation, `Use this stage to perform additional initialization steps using the rendered content, such as activating third-party JavaScript libraries that operate on the rendered DOM elements.`

***Disclaimer, I couldn't get this to work for my application. I could only get JS to work within a post-render action like a button-click. But this seems like where MS wants us to go to get JS running at page-load. So I only hope this points you in the right direction.

Note: Also, try to get off of JS where you can. Blazor should have the tools to do what JS is doing.